# Making SVG icons and font icons work together

Tags: css, svg, responsive-design, icon-fonts

I've noticed in my layouts that if I choose to use SVG icons, it is difficult to incorporate icon fonts as a backup. For example, if I have an SVG in a fluid container, an icon font inside this fluid container would not get bigger as its size is based on font-size. Does this mean I should use png backup files on SVG, since they follow the same format in my CSS? I am concerned that this would diminish performance on devices that don't support SVG.

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: I read the docs. I don't see anything wrong with this question. Unless you interpreted it as "your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?” While I have a solution to my problem, it is not ideal. And while I know the solution that is ideal, I wanted to know if anyone knows a proper way of implementing it.

Comment: It seem to me that you are asking for opinions...and those are off-topic. Others might disagree.